# JPA Hibernate missing column name in generated prepared statement

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm having trouble getting an audit trail to post to a table.

The error states that the field "changed_by" doesn't have a default value (which i do not wish for it to have a default value or be null)

I noticed that the prepared statement that it generated doesn't include the column even though i gave it a value.

here is my audit model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "audit_trail")
public class AuditTrail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "changed_msg", nullable = false, length = 1000)
    private String changed_msg;

    @MapsId
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="changed_by", nullable = false)
    private User changed_by;

    @MapsId
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id", nullable = false)
    private People personId;

    @Column(name="when_occured", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private Date when;



    public AuditTrail() {
    }

//plus accessors
}
```

and here is the method I'm calling using postman for testing:

```
    @PostMapping("/people/{id}/audittrail")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<AuditTrail> addAudit(@PathVariable("id") long personId, @RequestBody Map<String, String> requestBody, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String headers){
        AuditTrail auditTrail = new AuditTrail();
        People person= peopleRepository.findById(personId).get();
        if (headers != null) {
            if (sessionRepository.findByToken(headers).isPresent()) {
                if (requestBody.containsKey("changed_msg")) {
                    auditTrail.setChanged_msg(requestBody.get("changed_msg"));
                    auditTrail.setPersonId(person);
                    Session user = sessionRepository.findByToken(headers).get();
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss");
                    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    auditTrail.setWhen(date);
                    auditTrail.setChanged_by(user.getUser()); 
// as a note above is where i'm setting the changed by, below I printed the user val out and it gave me the user value that i expected.
                    System.out.println("User: "+user.getUser());
                    AuditTrail temp = new AuditTrail();
                    try {
                        temp = auditTrailRepository.save(auditTrail);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(temp, HttpStatus.valueOf(200));
                }
                else
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(auditTrail, HttpStatus.valueOf(400));
            }
            else
                return new ResponseEntity<>(auditTrail, HttpStatus.valueOf(401));
        }
        else
            return new ResponseEntity<>(auditTrail, HttpStatus.valueOf(401));
    }
```

here are the 2 parts i noted from the stacktrace:

```
Hibernate: insert into audit_trail (changed_msg, when_occured, person_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'changed_by' doesn't have a default value
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get it to add "changed_by" to the generated prepared statement as it is missing.

here is the full stacktrace:

```
Hibernate: insert into audit_trail (changed_msg, when_occured, person_id) values (?, ?, ?)
2021-12-03 23:46:05.667  WARN 15452 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
2021-12-03 23:46:05.667 ERROR 15452 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'changed_by' doesn't have a default value
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.save(Unknown Source)
    at springboot.services.PeopleControllerHibernate.addAudit(PeopleControllerHibernate.java:188)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3298)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3825)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'changed_by' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1340)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 85 more
```

Comment: What is the value of `user.getUser()` in the line `auditTrail.setChanged_by(user.getUser());` ?

Comment: it prints out the user name which is ragnar (test user). obtained by using sessionId to grab the user who has that session id.

Comment: The code you posted should not be having this problem.